# iOS Safari RTL Offset issue using -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch and -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0)

Tags: html, ios, css, webkit, right-to-left

i am working on a complex control and we have found a bug in RTL mode (only) in mobile Safari. Now i have stripped down the functionality to basic div containers (seems like jsfiddle does not support RTL mode).

RTL (Issue):
http://markuskonrad.de/concepts/overflow/overflowissue-rtl.html

LTR (Regular - No Issue):
http://markuskonrad.de/concepts/overflow/overflowissue-ltr.html

Tested device:

- iPad 2 (iOS 8.2)
- iPad Mini (iOS 8.3)
- iPad Air (iOS 8.3)
- iPhone 4 (iOS 7.1)

May it be possible that there is a Safari Mobile Bug? I am only facing this issue there.

I know the translate3d is a hack for hardware acceleration and without we are facing some rendering issue of sub elements of the scrollContent-Div. So the only option currently is waiting for support of [will-change](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/will-change) property. Any other ideas?

HTML-Code

```
<html dir="rtl" lang="en-US">
<head>
    <link href="Styles/overflowissue.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="scrollContainer" class="mySuiteUiScrollContainer">
        <div id="scrollContent">
            <p>
                123456789_123456789_123456789_123456789_123456789_123456789_123456789_123456789_123456789_123456789_123456789_123456789_123456789_123456789_
                123456789_123456789_123456789_123456789_123456789_123456789_123456789_123456789_123456789_123456789_123456789_123456789_123456789_123456789_
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS-Code

```
.mySuiteUiScrollContainer {
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color:red;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.mySuiteUiScrollContainer > * {
    clear: both;
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color:blue;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0 ,0 ,0);
}
```

[image: iPad Air example]

Thanks and BR,
Markus